# How to assign each element/column of output to a different variable

Tags: matlab, vector, variable-assignment

In Matlab some functions adapt their output to the number of output variables in the call. For example I can do:

```
A=[[1 2 3];[4 5 6]];
s=size(A);
```

And I get

```
s=[2, 3];
```

But if I want to handle independently width and height I can do:

```
[h, w]=size(A);
```

And I get:

h=2;
w=3;

Now, if I have a function that **always output a vector** of let's say 3 elements. **Is there a way to assign each element to a different variable?**
I mean to avoid an scenery like this:

```
pos=getPosition();
X=pos(1);
Y=pos(2);
Z=pos(3);
```

I hope I have explained what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Mostly with functions handling coordinates as in your  example. My solution was to create the following function:

```
function varargout = dealOneByOne(vector)
% Assign each column of vector to each variable on the output variables
%
    for i=1:size(vector,2)
        varargout{i}=vector(:,i);
    end
end
```

Then you can just do

```
[X,Y,Z]=dealOneByOne(getPosition());
```

I'm not aware of a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define a test function as follows:

```
function x = test()
    x = [1 2 3];
end
```

Given the function above, this is what I would normally perform in order to split the output array into many distinct variables:

```
out = num2cell(test());
[a,b,c] = deal(out{:});
```

A wrapper function can be defined in order to avoid spreading the above assignment into multiple lines:

```
[a,b,c] = vout_num(test());

function varargout = vout_num(x)
    C = num2cell(x);
    varargout = C(:).';
end
```

In your example, the wrapper function would be used as follows:

```
[X,Y,Z] = vout_num(getPosition());
```